# Powershell Azure See Cannot See what groups a contact is in

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I am trying to see the groups a contact is apart of. To provide some background, the contact is hidden in the directory of the tenet I am looking in because it is the alias of a sister tenet that the user is actually apart of. I am using PS and the cmd runs but displays no results. Can someone tell me where I may be going wrong? The users email address is stored in variable string called contact

Code:

```
Get-MsolGroup -All | Where-Object {$_.Members -contains $contact}
```

When I enter this command in PowerShell I do not get any results displayed

Comment: Are you sure that `Get-MsolGroup` returns all members of a group and that you don't need to use `Get-MsolGroupMember` ?

Comment: Hey Santiago thank you I am trying to return the groups the contact is apart of. It is my understanding that Get-MsolGroup returns the groups and Get-MscolGroupMember will give me the members

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested but, I believe this should work. It should return the `ObjectId` and `DisplayName` of the Groups where `$contact` is a member of.

```
$groups = Get-MsolGroup -All
$contact = 'someUser@someCompany.com'

foreach($group in $groups)
{
    $members = Get-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId $group.ObjectId

    if($contact -in $members.EmailAddress)
    {
        $group | Select-Object ObjectId, DisplayName
    }
}
```

Comment: Will test and follow up thank you so much Santiago!

Comment: @Britt of course, I hope it works. I've never used the `MSOnline` Module so not even sure what the cmdlets return. Would recommend you to move on to the [`AzureAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0&preserve-view=true) Module as it is quite newer.

Comment: @Britt so for some reason, you must add `-All` to `Get-MsolGroupMember` ? That is strange, I really recommend you to move on to the Azure AD Module. This sounds like a bug and Msol is really old.

Comment: Hey Santiago, yes that's the part! lol Yes I was thinking about the transition it really is limited support with this one i have found